# What is the difference between the two ways of uncovering things piecewise?

Tags: beamer, uncover

what is the difference between this

```
 \begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[A]
    \item<2-5> one thing.
    \item<3-5> another.
    \item<4-5> anther.    
\end{enumerate}
\uncover<1-5>{Hints:}\\
\uncover<2-5>{NO.}\\
\uncover<3-5>{NO.}\\
\uncover<4-5>{what do you think!!!!!}
\end{frame}
```

and this

```
 \begin{frame}

\begin{enumerate}[A]
    \item<2-> one thing.
    \item<3-> another.
    \item<4-> anther.    
\end{enumerate}
\uncover<1->{Hints:}\\
\uncover<2->{NO.}\\
\uncover<3->{NO.}\\
\uncover<4->{what do you think!!!!!}
\end{frame}
```

update

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[A]
    \item<2-5> one thing.
    \item<3-5> another.
    \item<4-> \color<6->{blue}anther.  
    \item<5-5> anther.   
\end{enumerate}
\uncover<1-5>{Hints:}\\
\uncover<2-5>{NO.}\\
\uncover<3-5>{NO.}\\
\uncover<4-5>{hmmmm}\\
\uncover<5-5>{what do you think!!!!!}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: The difference is that you have to know the last frame in the first example. The second one uses the last frame (of the animation) automatically.

Comment: that is all?. so if i got to the last frame which is <5-5> then i used <6-> will it act normally.

Comment: What do you mean with "act normally"? If you have a last frame with `<5-5>` you will add another frame to the animation as soon as you use the `6`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: sorry for not being clear.
i'm learning beamer and i found this ( the code in the update) 
and what it does it animated everything in sequence then everything dissappear but the colored one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general syntax of overlay specifications is

```
<"start number"-"end number">
```

For example `<3-5>` will be displayed on the 3rd, 4th and 5th overlay. If something should be displayed until the last overlay, the "end number" can be omitted, e.g. `<3->`. Similar `<-3>` will display on all overlays until the 3rd.

There are a few useful replacements for absolute numbers:

- `.` can be used in lieu of the current overlay number
- `+` as replacement for the next overlay number
- `(...)` to mark an offset, e.g. `<+(1)->` will display from one after the next overlay.

For more information, see "3.10 Using Overlay Specifications" and "9.6.4 Incremental Specifications" of the [beamer user guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).